# Click a Bootstrap link by hovering another link over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple tabs using `nav-tabs`. I want to drag `<li>` elements from one of those tabs to another by dragging over the tab, switching to the tab and dropping the item.

Comment: I recommend using this drag and drop library (Dragula). I've used it in several of my projects and it works flawlessly. The owner also gives good documentation. https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

Comment: You could also use jQueryUI `.sortable()`, http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/EgqMpa